# Can you define a variable in MATLAB like a set?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, 3d, set

I want to be able to deal with 3d structures in MATLAB. I'm new to MATLAB, and I haven't seen an answer to this question after googling it.

If you want to define a specific sphere explicitly, without using the built in sphere function, how would this work? For example, is there a way you could define a variable r = (1,1,1) in the xyz coordinate system, and then define a new variable/set S = {all s: distance (r,s) <= radius)}. It would be immensely handy if I could do that, but I'm not sure how MATLAB could deal with something like that, as it would involve an infinite set of points, so MATLAB would have to have some defined maximum resolution. Is this possible? It would be great to be able to define 3d structures in this way. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If by

> *all s: distance (r,s) <= radius)*

you mean

> *all s **in R<sup>3</sup>**: distance (r,s) <= radius)*

then the answer is:

- No, you can't define that set [by extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Describing_sets) (that is, enumerating all its elements), because the set has [uncountably infinitely many elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set).
- But you can define that set *S* [by intension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Describing_sets). This means that you can build a **rule** (a function) that, given any value *x* in R<sup>3</sup>, will tell you if *x* is in *S* or not.

Namely, that rule can be built using an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) as follows:

```
>> r = [1 1 1]; %// set center
>> radius = 2;  %// set radius
>> inS = @(s) sqrt(sum((s-r).^2))<radius;
```

The function `inS` returns `true` (`1`) if and only if its input belongs to *S*, and `false`(`0`) otherwise. For example,

```
>> inS([0 0 0])
ans =
     1
>> inS([3 4 5])
ans =
     0
>> inS([pi sqrt(2) exp(-1)])
ans =
     0
```

This is probably the closest you can get to "defining" that set.

If you want to test **several values at once**, instead of using a loop you can [vectorize the function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
>> inS = @(s) sqrt(sum((bsxfun(@minus, s, r)).^2, 2))<radius;
>> points = [ 0 0 0
              3 4 5
              pi sqrt(2) exp(-1) ];
>> inS(points)
ans =
     1
     0
     0
```

Comment: Thanks! Great example, this is exactly what I meant. I take it you could then write a loop which could run through all 3d coordinates like a grid with an arbitrary resolution, and assign values to approximate the shape of a 3d object, in the manner you say

Comment: Yes, you could use a loop. But it's better to vectorize the function, so that it takes all values at once. See edit

Comment: Good answer! But I think it's called "uncountably infinitely many elements".

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like the following:

```
r=1;
resolutionPhi=50;
resolutionTheta=60;
phi=linspace(0,pi,resolutionPhi); %linspace gives (50) equally spaced points between (0) and (pi)
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,resolutionTheta);
[phi,theta]=meshgrid(phi,theta); %meshgrid replicates the vectors into a rectangular array

 x=r*sin(phi).*cos(theta);
 y=r*sin(phi).*sin(theta);
 z=r*cos(phi);
```

You can adjust the resolution by changing the resolution variables.